# The space of ergodic elements of a topological or Lie group

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems, harmonic-analysis, ergodic-theory

Let  $G$  be  a  compact topological group with normalized  Haar measure $\mu$. An  element $g\in G$ is  an ergodic element if the mapping $L_g:G \to G $  with $x\mapsto gx$ is  an ergodic map. The set of ergodic elements of a group $G$ is denoted by $E(G)$

> Is there  a  compact topological group or a compact Lie group for  which the set of  all ergodic elements have intermediate  measure  namely  we have $0<\mu(E(G)<1$?

Comment: Yes, the finite group $\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$ is an example. The set of ergodic elements has cardinal 2, hence measure $1/2$.

Comment: @YCor  Yes  thank  you that is  perfect. I was  inspired  by the circle  case. The ergodic element has  full measure. So what about we  add the  extra  assumption connected lie  group? BTW is there  an example  of  empty  or  zero measure  set of  ergodic  elements?

Comment: @YCor  ecause in the Lie  group case  a  subgroup can not have  intermediate  measure but in you example  the  subgroup has  index 2

Comment: You mean "in the connected case". Every finite group is a Lie group.

Comment: @YCor  I mean in the connected  case. However  your first  coment is  a  ful answer  to my  question. But  I try to extend the  question

Comment: For a connected compact nonabelian Lie group there are no ergodic elements. For a connected compact abelian Lie group almost all elements are ergodic.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you! I think you are indicating to the Maximal torus and foliati9n of G with this torus. yes?

Comment: two conjugate 3lements have the  sam3 ergodic type but all elements are conjugate to som3 g in T

Comment: @MoisheKohan  what about the following modified question: a connected compact Lie group for which the set of all elements with dense orbit has an intermediate measure

Comment: My previous comment answers the modified question: there are no such groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Ah yes again Maximal torus the orbit remain there forever